# iOS/autolayout/storyboard: Apply constraint to Searchbar in tableview

Tags: ios, autolayout, uisearchbar

In order to have a tableview adapt to screen size, I have constrained it to its parent view.  However, now when I do this, the Search bar--which used to fill up the whole navigation bar, leaves a space to the right and is in fact smaller than the tableview.

When I try to apply constraints to the search bar, however, they don't take.  If I control drag from the searchbar to the container view in storyboard, there are no constraint options, only gives the a delegate option.  And if I click on the auto layout buttons, they don't allow you to set any constraints for the search bar.  So at this point I am stuck.

This is how I want the search bar to look:

[image]

This is how it now looks.

[image]

Can anyone suggest how to make the search bar look like the first example--the same width as the navigation bar.  Thank you.

Edit:

Storyboard:

[image]

Comment: put Search bar in the Header of your `tableView`

Comment: You mean create a header view for the uitableview and move the searcher into it?  The search bar is already the view immediately below the tableview which I think is where header goes. I tried to insert another uiview directly below the tableview but it does not allow me to do so.

Comment: Yes , you can just drag and drop `UIView` inside your `tableView` above your `tableCell`  ....And than put your search bar into this header view.

Comment: It's not letting me do that.  Possibly because the search bar which is a `UIView`  is already above the `tableCell`

Comment: I don't have team viewer.

Comment: see tutorial .. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ZBREmCCJXA

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143709/discussion-between-dhiru-and-zztop).